# KSP VS1 VTOL Engine. Can't 'Run Test'

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have been given a contract to test the VS1 VTOL engine while landed but I can't because the Right-Click menu is so big it goes off the screen!

How do I work around this?

Comment: The part you mention isn't a stock engine. Does it come from a mod? Maybe that mod doesn't play well with the contract system... You might want to notify the creator about the issue.

Comment: Maybe. I thought only stock parts were in contracts. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the screen around by holding the middle mouse button. You should be able to move around enough such that the button is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Most part testing contracts can also be completed by activating the part by staging (hitting `Space` key).

Might want to throttle down if its an asymmetric testing craft so that you don't flip out

Comment: Hehehe, 'flip out'

Comment: The VTOL does not appear in the staging area and throttling to 0 and then up doesn't work. Neither does shutting it down and activating it again.

Comment: This is a mod part right?